# Is there a way to automatically fill out a PDF form with data generated from a query in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, adobe

I am using SQLDeveloper to query an oracle database and I want to schedule this query to occur every day at the same time.  When this query executes, is there a way to set the file path so that each row from the results gets filled out in its own pdf form (the pdf is fillable)?  Could this work in Adobe Acrobat Pro?  Should the data from the query be saved in a csv?  What is the appropriate way to save the data so that it can be exported to be written into the pdf forms?

Edit: I want to set up an automatic execution of my SQL query in SQLDeveloper, possibly using something like PL/SQL.  This query should execute once a day.  Every time it executes, I want the results of the query to be sent into a form that I created in Adobe Acrobat Pro.

For example: SQL query returns several 5 attributes about a car for a set of 100 cars, and for each row returned, it will fill out a PDF form with that data.  How do I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this edit clarify anything?